# handler messages re-executed on resuming activity

Tags: android, gps, handler, message

My program try to get GPS location every time in interval defined by user

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(Call_GPS); }
```

For this purpose, I create message handler, and I use sendEmptyDelayedMessage with an amount of delay entered by user. In the message I call getLocation() method which start taking GPS coordinates and save them

```
@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case Call_GPS:
            getLocation();
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(Call_GPS,Integer.parseInt(Settings.GPSInt)*60000);
        super.handleMessage(msg);
            break;}}};
```

This code work well also with the onPause() and take gps coordinates in interval as user request.

My problem is that if I return from onPause() to UI (onResume()) the program start retaking GPS coordinates, so please help me.

Hint: I searched on the internet about this, I read that the handler run on the UI thread, and I think this is the reason of my problem, but I don't know the solution

Note: Please avoid proposing the solution of changing the updaterequest in getLocation(), I need the solution about handler

Comment: In which method have you written this `Handler` code??

Comment: The handler code is written in the same class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution
it is by calling the handler from onCreate() instead of onStart ()

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what behaviour you would like, but if you want the requests to stop in onPause and not start again when the user comes back to the app then you need to remove the pending messages from the Handler in onPause(). Otherwise they will still be there in the queue when the app comes back in onResume and will continue to fire.

Comment: I mean that the handler receive sendEmptyMessageDelayed(). In normal case, taking new location must be restarted after the defined delay. But what happens, is when I return from onPause () to onResume (), the handler start executing the message and taking GPS coordinates, this mean it doesn't continue the delay to be completed to start taking new location. Please let me know if the question now is clear